# Can we use R.java to recieve values in one layout in another layout?

Tags: android

trying to fetch text box data entered in one layout to be populated in another layout.Is this doable through R.java.Dont want to use intent.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible. You have to use intent for this.